# Ubuntu suggestion to dual boot with windows in a lightweight PC

Tags: dual-boot, distro-recommendation

I'm using widows xp(32 bit). The hardware details for my computer are:

> Pentium 4 cpu 1.6 GHz, 
>   1 gb RAM, 
>   80 gb hard disk.
>   no graphics card
>   Is Ubuntu 9.10 will be a best option in dual booting for my computer?

Comment: That's not enough information to determine which version would work best. How much RAM does your computer have, also, what graphics card?

Comment: Also processor model for determining its execution speed would be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on how long you intend to keep that hardware running.

Depending on that, use the oldest LTS release that will still be supported when your hardware is gone, as the newer ones possibly demand more from your hardware (especially graphics card and memory).

You can find the lifespan of Ubuntu releases here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/) and especially at the part [minimal installations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Minimal_installations) of ubuntu to see if your hardware matches and how you can install ubuntu on older systems. It's in general hard to say "this hardware will definetly work" or "definitely not", give it a try. You should make sure that you test an installation via live-cd (if available). If you experience graphical problems during installation, try the [alternate-CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).
[Here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aNatty) you can find the requirements for older ubuntu versions.